# Sonar not analyzing Android xml files

Tags: android, sonarqube

I'm adding a job in Jenkins to analyze an android project, but I can't get it to take into account the xml files (in res/ and subdirectories).

My sonar.properties:

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=AndroidProj
sonar.projectName=AndroidProj
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# path to source directories (required)
sonar.sources=src
sonar.binaries=bin/classes

# The value of the property must be the key of the language.
sonar.language=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.profile=Android Lint
```

What this gives me in the SonarQube web UI is only the java files (and indeed `sonar.language=java` should be an indication of this), so how could I go to get a Lint check on the xml files?

Setting `sonar.language=xml` doesn't go well with `sonar.profile=Android Lint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SonarQueb does not correctly support multi-language projects, the Android plugin indeed only reports issues on Java files.

Our goal is obviously to report also issues on XML files as soon as the multi-language support is ready. You can vote for the following ticket and watch it to know the progress: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-926

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get it: isn't multi-language support [already implemented](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/multi-language)?. I use Sonar to analyze another project with two submodules (one 'js' and the other 'web') and it works wonders. Besides, the ticket you refer too is "closed (fixed)".

Comment: Btw, a similar question could be "is there any way to do an Android Lint analysis to the xml files only?". I could live with the idea of doing multiple analysis.

Comment: Ooops, was a bad copy-paste, I edited my answer with the correct URL. I'm talking about full support of multi-language, what SonarQube currently offers is just a workaround.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense! In the meantime, do you think that a separate Android Lint analysis of only the xml files would be possible?

Comment: Not with the current version of the plugin. And unfortunately, we won't invest time in this before the multi-language support is done (which already consumes time on our side!).

Comment: Fait enough. Can't wait to see the multi-language support coming in, then. Bon courage! :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbled upon this issue with later versions of SonarQube (I am using 5.3), you need the following things:

1. Android Plugin installed
2. XML Plugin installed
3. remove the "sonar.language" property so that sonar can detect the languages used there by default
4. add your res folder to your "sonar.sources" property. Mine looks like this:

   ```
   property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java,src/main/res"
   ```

   (defined in a sonarqube properties block in gradle).